# How to return same object with linq as with lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use object with Entity Framework Core when I use linq query. But object is always anonymous, which I don't want. I have this code:

```
                var query = (from c in context.UserTest
                         join k in context.OneToTest on c.FkOneToTestId equals k.Id
                         select new { c, k }).ToList();
```

which is anonymous object. But with this code:

```
 var test = context.UserTest
            .Include(one => one.OneToTest)
            .ToList();
```

I want to have same object in **query** and **test**.Now in *test* is `List<UserTest>` and in *query* `List<'a>`. Is there any easy way how to do it with linq?

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking. What you call **test** is the EF Core recommended (intended) way to do what you call **query**. In LINQ to Entities we don't use manual joins as in the regular LINQ, because we don't need them - navigation properties do that for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
var test = context.UserTest.Include(one => one.OneToTest).ToList();
```

is:

```
var test = (from c in context.UserTest.Include(one => one.OneToTest)
            select c).ToList();
```

The only way I know to not use Include is to create a new object, where you don't need the join:

```
var test = (from c in context.UserTest
            select new UserTest
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    OneToTest = c.OneToTest,
                    // ...
                }).ToList();
```